# Entity model relationships?

Tags: entity-framework, relationship

I create a table named Posts.

```
POSTS        |
_____________|
post_id      |
parent_id    |  //reference to post_id
post_type_id |  //I have two type
user_id      |  //reference to user table
```

I create a entity model from this table. I expect this: `Model.POSTS` But It is shown like this `Model.POSTS1` and `Model.POSTS2` It means there are two collections.

Why this is happened? It is about post_type? `POSTS1 = type1` and `POSTS2=type2`?

Comment: Did you look at the mappings?  What is Model.POSTS2 mapped to?

Comment: they are mapped to posts, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry They mapped to different. Post1 is a collection Post2 is one object. This mean if post is children it refer to one parent. If post is parent it refer to its childs(collection).